# Calculate standard deviation (σ) from the previous one and a new element (cumulative/incremental SD)

Tags: javascript, typescript, statistics, benchmarking

A running process is being benchmarked, where the following numbers are calculated "cumulatively" (from previous values + the new element):

- Minimum duration
- Maximum duration
- Average duration

The **[Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) (σ) of the duration** is supposed to be calculated as well, because it indicates the [statistical dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_dispersion).

Based on the application, it is inconvenient to store each and every element/number, so it is necessary to calculate it with respect to the previous value and the new element.

Example:

```
NewElement  Min  Max  Avg  StdDev           // AllElements (which are NOT meant to be stored)
1           1    1    1    -                   [1]
2           1    2    1.5  0.5                 [1,2]
3           1    3    2    0.8164965809277     [1,2,3]
4           1    4    2.5  1.1180339887499     [1,2,3,4]
0           0    4    2    1.4142135623731     [1,2,3,4,0]
```

(And [this](https://academo.org/demos/standard-deviation-calculator/) is an online calculator of SD, for reference values)

A simplified version of the goal would be:

```
const calculateNewStats = (stats, newElement) => {
  const newStats = {};
  newStats.count = stats.count + 1;
  newStats.min = Math.min(stats.min, newElement);
  newStats.max = Math.max(stats.max, newElement);
  newStats.avg = (stats.avg * stats.count + newElement) / newStats.count;

  // newStats.sd = ??? that's the problem

  return newStats;
};

// initial values
let stats = {
  count: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 0,
  avg: 0,
  // initial SD is theoretically controversial (N/A), but that's not the point
  sd: 0,
};

// loopStart goes here ... an infinite one

    // many things goes here ... eventually, we have a `newElement`

    stats = calculateNewStats(stats, newElement);

// loopEnd goes here
```

A search has been made for some time, some mathematical equations (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/775678/503493)) were found and carefully applied but the resulted numbers were not correct.

Comment: I think it is something like `Math.sqrt((stats.sd + Math.pow(newElement - stats.avg, 2)) / 2)` but I'm not sure if you can calculate it without all the data.

Comment: @Titus Applying it for elements `[1,2]` => `Math.sqrt((0 + Math.pow(0 - 1, 2)) / 2)` the result is **0.707106** where the expected result is **0.5**

Comment: Instead of `stats.avg` I should have used `newStats.avg` but that gives the wrong result as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm on [the page you linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/775678/19636) does work, here is a working implementation:

```js
const calculateNewStats = (stats, newElement) => {
  const newStats = {};

  newStats.count = stats.count + 1;
  newStats.min = Math.min(stats.min, newElement);
  newStats.max = Math.max(stats.max, newElement);
  newStats.avg = (stats.avg * stats.count + newElement) / newStats.count;

  newStats.sd = Math.sqrt(
    (
      (newStats.count - 1) * stats.sd * stats.sd +
      (newElement - newStats.avg) * (newElement - stats.avg)
    ) / (newStats.count)
  );

  return newStats;
};

// initial values
let stats = {
  count: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 0,
  avg: 0,
  sd: 0
};

let newElements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0];

for (let newElement of newElements) {
  stats = calculateNewStats(stats, newElement);
  console.log(stats);
}
```

[Result on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/ximimefexa/1/edit?js,console)

Maybe you missed the last sentence?

> If you want the population variance or standard deviation replace N-1 with N and N-2 with N-1.

---

Note: there will be a small loss of precision that will get larger as you add elements. I would advise to:

- store the variance in `stats` together with `sd`; right now I'm calculating the square root of the variance to get the SD, then squaring the SD to get the variance in the next iteration
- store the total value in `stats`, instead of recalculating it with `stats.avg * stats.count` on every iteration

You're storing 2 more numbers in `stats`, but you should be getting a better precision in your numbers.

This is a better implementation:

```js
const calculateNewStats = (stats, newElement) => {
  const newStats = {};
  newStats.count = stats.count + 1;
  newStats.total = stats.total + newElement;
  newStats.min = Math.min(stats.min, newElement);
  newStats.max = Math.max(stats.max, newElement);
  newStats.avg = (stats.total + newElement) / newStats.count;

  newStats.variance = (
    (newStats.count - 1) * stats.variance +
    (newElement - newStats.avg) * (newElement - stats.avg)
  ) / (newStats.count);

  newStats.sd = Math.sqrt(newStats.variance);

  return newStats;
};

// initial values
let stats = {
  count: 0,
  total: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 0,
  avg: 0,
  sd: 0,
  variance: 0
};

let newElements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0];

for (let newElement of newElements) {
  stats = calculateNewStats(stats, newElement);
  console.log(stats);
}
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hapimibotu/edit?js,console)

Comment: and I would rather store the variance as you suggested to avoid sqrt then pow2 operations. However, I do not see the benefit of storing the total, it is not being used anyways!

Comment: @Hossam: the total is being used to recompute the average.  `newStats.avg = (stats.total + newElement) / newStats.count;`  (Instead of *storing* the average, it's just an output computed from the total.)  This lets you accumulate more elements cheaply if you ever have multiple elements to add *without* needing the expensive incremental outputs for each one.

Comment: @PeterCordes yea I just noticed, but this would not affect the precision I think, because both avg and count are integers

Comment: @Hossam: no, `count` is an integer, and `total`is if you only pass integer inputs.  But one of your averages in your example in the question is `1.5`.  It happens that `1.5` can be represented exactly as a `double`, but the average of `[1, 0, 0]` is `1/3` which can't be represented exactly.  Only fractions with a power-of-2 denominator can be represented exactly by a binary floating point number.  Either way, tracking the total is less total work than tracking the average.